# How to make Ubuntu the main OS

Tags: boot, partitioning

I had a windows on my laptop. I wanted to install Ubuntu so I partitioned it before installing however I mistakenly wiped the windows OS out of the laptop(which I don’t mind). Now when I power my laptop I need to go to the boot menu to get Ubuntu to load on it (otherwise it tell me that there no bootable drive). It still shows as though there were a partitioning. How can I clear the partition or make Ubuntu the main OS to load from when I power it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply change the boot device in BIOS and point at ubuntu disk.
if this is not about BIOS boot menu, please clarify in the question what menu you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I always go to the boot menu of the BIOS. To boot Ubuntu. If I fail to do this it the system tells me there is no bootable drive, I asking because I expect since Ubuntu is the only OS present on my machine. It should boot automatically whenever I power it .... that’s is what I’m trying to achieve

Comment: that's what I'm suggesting. If you enter your bios settings there's a way to change the priority of boot devices, so you don't have to enter the boot menu and coose ubuntu drive each time. you can make the ubuntu drive "default first" boot device so it always try to boot from it first.